# How could I get a part of a match string by RegEx in Python?

Tags: python, regex, web-crawler

I'm now making a web-spider by python,and some part of the program requests me to get some strings like data-id="48859672" from a website. I've successfully got these strings using:

```
pattern=re.compile(r'\bdata-id="\d+"')
m=pattern.search(html,start)
```

But I'm now wondering how to only get the number part of the strings,except the whole string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) or [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
>>> pattern=re.compile(r'\bdata-id="(\d+)"')
>>> s = 'data-id="48859672"'
>>> pattern.search(s).group(1)
'48859672'
```

OR

```
>>> pattern=re.compile(r'(?<=\bdata-id=")\d+(?=")')
>>> s = 'data-id="48859672"'
>>> pattern.search(s).group()
'48859672'
```